# Create an Array from data

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array from this data, but I don´t get it. I tried with the `array_merge` function, but the array doesn't construct correctly. This is my code, I want to create an array with the different fields of the table.

```
<?php
require('extractorhtml/simple_html_dom.php');
$dom = new DOMDocument();

//load the html
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile("http:");


//discard white space
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

//the table by its tag name
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

//get all rows from the table
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
echo '<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="find" />';
echo '<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped display">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Date</th>';
echo '<th>Hour</th>';
echo '<th>Competition</th>';
echo '<th>Event</th>';
echo '<th>Chanel</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
// loop over the table rows
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    // get each column by tag name
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    // echo the values
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$cols->item(3)->nodeValue.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-primary">'.$cols->item(4)->nodeValue.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$cols->item(5)->nodeValue.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Where is array_merge at in this? And where are you trying to create an array?

Comment: I want to create an array with the date,hour,competition and channel data of the table, I tried with array_merge but i don´t know how to get the data of each field of the table and put it into array correctly

Comment: What is in `$tables`? Also, show your relevant attempts. It helps us know what you are thinking cause right now it is very unclear.

Comment: `array_merge` is used when you have two arrays and you want to combine them into one array. You don't have any arrays to combine, so what do you think you need to merge?

Comment: @htmlpower you might want to take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and refactor your question a bit to help us understand what you have and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to merge arrays, you just need to push onto a new array to create a 2-dimensional array.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    // get each column by tag name
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    // echo the values
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$cols->item(3)->nodeValue.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-primary">'.$cols->item(4)->nodeValue.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$cols->item(5)->nodeValue.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $new_array[] = array(
        'date' => $cols->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'hour' => $cols->item(1)->nodeValue,
        'competition' => $cols->item(3)->nodeValue,
        'channel' => $cols->item(5)->nodeValue
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `<th>` values, you know which columns contain which values, so it looks like you'd just need to modify the code inside your `foreach` loop to append the values to an array rather than generating new HTML with them.

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    // get each column by tag name
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

    $array['date'] = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $array['hour'] = $cols->item(1)->nodeValue;
    $array['competition'] = $cols->item(3)->nodeValue;
    $array['event'] = $cols->item(4)->nodeValue;
    $array['chanel'] = $cols->item(5)->nodeValue;
    $result[] = $array;
}
```

After this loop, `$result` will be an array of arrays containing the values from the `<td>`s, where each inner array represents one `<tr>`.